# SQL Server started, but SQL Server Management Studio not connecting to it

Tags: sql-server, sql-management-studio

**Problem statement**

I have installed (Developer Edtion) and started my SQL Server, but when trying to connect to it through SQL Server Management Studio, it shows this error:

[image]

---

My configuration for SQL Server Management Studio:

[image]

Proof that SQL Server is running:

[image]

Further proof (taken from services.msc):

[image]

---

This is persistent problem that has plagued me for many days now and I cannot understand what is wrong. If I am not mistaken, the error (the first image) only appears when the server does not exist or is not running. Then how am I getting the error if I seem to have set up everything correctly?

Comment: have you tried just putting in localhost? it's been a while since I did it, but you used to have to allow connection over named pipes or TCP/IP in SQL Server Configuration Manager before you can actually connect to the server. https://docs.sdl.com/801922/570899/sdl-tridion-docs-13-sp2/microsoft-sql-server-ports

Comment: @FrankThomas No, it's still the same error, unfortunately.

Comment: Did you select Named Instance or Default Instance during Install? if default, remove the \MSSQLSERVER, and just connect to localhost or the machine name. also have you opened firewall ports for 1433, and configured SQLServer to listen on TCP? run `netstat -abno | findstr LISTENING | findstr 1433` in an elevated powershell prompt. if you get no output, then your SQL server isn't listening for network connections, so you need to allow them. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/default-sql-server-network-protocol-configuration?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: @FrankThomas Yes, I have TCP/IP enabled for SQL Server. I connected to localhost via SQL Server Management Studio and I want you to take a look to see if what I am seeing the actual SQL Server that I installed. I want you to confirm or deny that I have succeeded at connecting to SQL Server. Here is what I connected to: https://gyazo.com/afb43f8f9f742c3be4454745ad6e1bf0

Comment: looks right to me. the DW* databases were created because you installed polybase. https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/premier-field-engineering/what-does-installing-polybase-add-to-sql-server/ba-p/370939

Comment: Alright, thank you very much! Please post your answer to my question @FrankThomas .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Modern MS SQLServer don't require you to use the name `MSSQLSERVER` to connect to the default instance anymore (I honestly don't recall that being a thing since SQLServer 2000). You will see the string in relation to services and processes however.

If you installed a Default Instance, just connect to the server name, without additional pathing (`localhost`, the hostname, or FQDN if you are hosting a DNS domain). If you have configured SQLServer to run on alternate ports, specify a port number with `<servername>:<TCP port num>`.

If you install a Named instance, the name will be the server name (via any of the expressions above), and append `\<instance name>`.

These statements are true even if you have installed a default and one or more named instances.